# implementing skip connection in neural nets in pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, implementation

I'm trying to implement skip connections in neural nets for tabular data in pytorch

[image: this is the format of skip connections I'm trying to implement]

code:

```
class EmbedNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, num_inputs=None, num_net_outputs=None, **kwargs):
    super(EmbedNet, self).__init__()
    self.layers = layers
    self.num_inputs = num_inputs
    self.num_net_outputs = num_net_outputs
    self.cat_cols = cat_cols
    self.numeric_cols = numeric_cols

    self.batchNorm1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_inputs)
    self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.15)
    self.dense1 = nn.utils.weight_norm(nn.Linear(num_inputs, 512))

    self.batchNorm2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(512)
    self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.15)
    self.dense2 = nn.utils.weight_norm(nn.Linear(512, 512))

    self.batchNorm4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(512)
    self.dropout4 = nn.Dropout(0.15)
    self.dense4 = nn.utils.weight_norm(nn.Linear(512, num_net_outputs))

    self.wide_block = nn.Linear(num_inputs, num_net_outputs)
    self.wide_block2 = nn.Linear(num_inputs, 512)        

def forward(self, x):       
    wide = self.wide_block(x)
    wide2 = self.wide_block2(x)
    x = self.batchNorm1(x)
    x = F.relu(self.dense1(x) + wide2)

    x = self.batchNorm2(x)
    x = self.dropout2(x)
    x = F.relu(self.dense2(x) + wide2)
    
    x = self.batchNorm4(x)
    x = self.dropout4(x)
    x = self.dense4(x)
    x = nn.Sigmoid()(wide + x)
    
    return x
```

This model is getting same results every time. It doesn't seem to learn anything.
what am I doing wrong here?
Is there any better way to implement skip connections in pytorch?
what is the best format to implement skip connections for tabular data?

Comment: The model looks good to me. The problem might be somewhere else. Did you try if you can overfit on a single batch? You need to be careful with batch norm not shift the norm parameters at the inference time. Layer norm is safer in this regard.